# Segmentation fault(code dumped) in c++ after several try I cann't get the solution

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T,D;
    long long int N;
    long long int a[N];
    long long int b[D];
    cin>>T;
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
       cin>>N>>D;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<D;i++)
        {
            b[i]=a[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<(N-D);i++)
        {
            a[i]=a[i+D];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<D;i++)
        {
            a[i+N]=b[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i];
        }        
             cout <<endl;
    }
    

    
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this coding having segmentation fault? I have seen many solution but cann't get it right.On visual studio or any other application it is not working but on gfg it is working. Please help me solve this problem

Comment: `int T,D; long long int N;` What are the values in `T`, `D`, and `N` at the time when you declare arrays to be those lengths (which isn't standard C++)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that are wrong.

C-style arrays must be set at compile time. So if you want to use int a[N], N must to known at compile time. If you want a flexible array, one C++ way is to use std::vector.

Then the array a goes from 0 to N-1. So going a[N] is going too far. So a[i+N] is way out if bounds and will be segfault.

Comment: In the posted code N isn’t even known at run-time (at least not until after the array has already been declared)

Answer (score 0):

you declare array a with N element, but use index out of the array range.

```
long long int a[N]; // declare here, maximum element is N
for(int i=0;i<D;i++)
{
    a[i+N]=b[i];    // use index out of array a
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank You ...... This Solved my problem